# excel vb sum & copy range with criteria

Tags: excel, vba, sumifs

I am new to excel visual basic, need some help as have been searching thru the web and can't figure out what is the right coding.

I want to sum up the daily sales by first criteria sales person - Robin & Ray from sheet2 (data range) to sheet1. I manged to do it and copy on 1/1, but unable to copy the rest of the colum from B,C,D...(2/1,3/1...)

Secondly, if i want to add second criteria on status, only pick up those 'Active' in column C (sheet2), what is the right code to use?

Can anyone direct me to the right place or coding? would very much appreciate your help.

Thanks

[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/5mEE8.png)

Comment: Do you need to do this by code, formula's are possible for this.

Comment: Hi, i have dynamic daily data to process, so, i was thinking it's good to use VB to do the automation process with a click of a button.

Answer (score 1):

In my opinion, you should avoid using VBA code to accomplish this objective, and use a Pivot Table instead. The way that you present the data is a little messy, but:

1. Convert the range in *Sheet2* into a Table. Make sure you include the headings.
2. From the Table menu, add a Pivot Table to a new sheet.
3. At the right of your screen, select *Sales-person* and drag it into the "Rows" box.
4. Then select each of the days u want to have and drag them into the "Measures" box. Change from *Count* to *Sum*.

You will have to add a new day every time that the table is updated, and I'm assuming it's every day... so I would suggest changing the structure of the original table, so you have one column with the date of each transaction, instead of one column per date.

Comment: Hi, i found it too texting to use pivot table as i have dynamic data to process daily, i like the idea of VB coding and automation process with a button. i want to copy the raw data and paste them in sheet2, there are more diifferent raw data, i plan to paste them in sheet3, sheet4 later on.....sheet1 is the summary sheet, with a click of button it sum up all the data by criteria, eg. sales person, so the VB coding cut short all the manual process. Thanks

Comment: Hi, anyone know how to tweak the code below? 

Sub sumif()

Sheet1.Range("A2") = "Robin"
Sheet1.Range("C2") = Application.WorksheetFunction.sumif(Sheet2.Range("b2:F6"), "Robin", Sheet2.Range("D2:D6"))
Range("A3") = "Ray"
Sheet1.Range("C3") = Application.WorksheetFunction.sumif(Sheet2.Range("b2:F6"), "Ray", Sheet2.Range("D2:d6"))

End Sub

Comment: Automation using VBA is of course a possibility, but the code you suggest will need to be changed as well every time... You'd need to use expressions that rely on relative references rather than absolutes.